# WCF service call issue c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I am calling a third party service in MVC application where I get it working if I pass the values in the endpoint in web.config

```
<endpoint address="address of svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IETDocService" contract="EDocService.IETDocService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IETDocService">
        <headers>
          <UserNameHeader xmlns="urn:-----" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
           <UserName xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2007/08/FT.DHM">john.cena@dmh.com</UserName>
            <Password xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2007/08/FT.DHM">32d698cf-51t5-4080-6d44-143e4432df73</Password>
          </UserNameHeader>
        </headers>
      </endpoint>
```

This configuration works fine, now I need to pass username and password dynamically but it is not working,below are the code I have tried,

Try 1

```
var endAdd = new EndpointAddressBuilder(loginService.Endpoint.Address);

            endAdd.Headers.Add(AddressHeader.CreateAddressHeader("UserName",                                                             string.Empty,   
                                                                request.UserName));
            endAdd.Headers.Add(AddressHeader.CreateAddressHeader("Password", 
                                                                string.Empty,   
                                                                request.Pwd));  

            loginService.Endpoint.Address = endAdd.ToEndpointAddress();
```

Try 2

```
ctWcf.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = this.MessageSigningCertificate;
            using (new OperationContextScope(ctWcf.InnerChannel))
            {

                UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo();
                userInfo.UserName = "john.cena@dmh.com";
                userInfo.Password = "32d698cf-51t5-4080-6d44-143e4432df73";
                MessageHeader aMessageHeader = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("UserNameHeader", "http://uddi.org", userInfo);
                OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(aMessageHeader);
            }
```

Not able to call the service,your help is really appreciated

Comment: Exception is
Authentication failed, invalid/expired authentication token or email/password combination

Comment: Have you tried turning on [WCF Tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/tracing-and-message-logging) to see what your outgoing message looks like? The approach you're taking in Try 2 is the correct one but you need to use a type that serializes you what the backend is expecting.

Comment: @AmithSewnarain thanks for the pointer, I added tracing and found that UserNameHeader is added when the header is specified in config file but when header is added in code "UserNameHeader " is not present

Comment: Just another question, you need to make the actual call to the backend within the using block. Are you doing so?

Comment: Getting the header now in the call. New error : System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException: Type 'UserNameHeader' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute. If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute

Comment: Got it Working. Thanks for the tracing suggestion.It helped a lot